# How to populate array outside of the closure in PHP?

Tags: php, hashmap, closures

I wrote this

```
 $result = array();

        array_map(function($row) use ($result) {
            $result[$row->id] = array();
            $result[$row->id]['geojson'] = $row->geojson;
        }, $regions);
```

and `$result` is empty at the end.

Is it possible to populate array this way?

Comment: Looks like it should work, what is `var_dump($regions);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$result` inside the function is a copy of the outer array, so changes you make don't affect the original. You need to use a reference: `use (&$result)`

```
array_map(function($row) use (&$result) {
    $result[$row->id] = array();
    $result[$row->id]['geojson'] = $row->geojson;
}, $regions);
```

Or you could simply use `foreach`

```
foreach ($regions as $row) {
    $result[$row->id] = array();
    $result[$row->id]['geojson'] = $row->geojson;
}
```